# How to discretize a continuous time domain state space model?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, discrete-time

Let's say I have a state space model of a linear dynamic system in the continuous time domain in following form

$$\dot{\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{u}$$

My goal is to implement the above given system in a control software which runs in a real time in a digital signal processor. This piece of software will be used as an open loop state observer of a real dynamic system. For software implementation purposes it is necessary to discretize the above given state space model.

I have a question regarding the discretization process. I have encountered basically two approaches to the discretization process

1. the discretization is done directly via below given transformation
   of the matrices of the state space model in the continuous time
   domain based on given sampling period $T$

   \begin{eqnarray}
   \mathbf{A}_d &=& \mathbf{I} + \frac{\mathbf{A}\cdot T}{2!} + 
   \frac{(\mathbf{A}\cdot T)^2}{3!} + \ldots = \mathbf{I} + 
   \mathbf{A}\cdot T\cdot\mathbf{\Psi} \\
   \mathbf{B}_d &=& \mathbf{B}\cdot T\cdot\mathbf{\Psi}
   \end{eqnarray}
2. the discretization is done indirectly via selection of the
   numerical method for solving the ordinary differential equations
   (*Euler*, *Adams-Bashforth*, *Runge-Kutta* etc.)

My question is whether there is any difference (as far as the outcomes of the resulting discrete model) between the above mentioned methods?

**Edit**:

As far as the first method. The derivation can be found e.g. in *Digital Control of Dynamic Systems* (Franklin, Powel, Workman) on page 101 - 106.

Comment: Can you explain more on the first method?

Comment: @A.J.Pan-Collantes thank you very much for your reaction. I have just appended the information regarding derivation of the first method to my question.